# Generating shapefiles from WKT format polygons using Arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, wkt

I am working with a database containing a geography field representing the Admin1 boundaries of countries. I would like to draw a map of the Admin1 boundaries of Somalia:

```
params = urllib.quote_plus(...)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
query = ("SELECT SimplifiedCoords.STAsText() FROM Adm1GeoBoundaries WHERE (Adm0Code = '226')")
df = pd.read_sql(query,engine)
```

this returns a list of the 18 subdivisions, e.g.:

```
0  POLYGON ((44.661 3.2516, 44.611 3.2715, 44.410...
1  POLYGON ((49.0611 9.571, 48.561 9.541, 48.061 ...
2  POLYGON ((44.2362 10.4724, 44.2021 10.5066, 44...
```

My issue now is to convert these into shapefiles in order to map them using arcpy. So far I have tried:

```
wkt = (df.loc[1]).to_string() # I only focus on one to test
g1 = loads(wkt)
```

But this throws : 
"ParseException: Expected number but encountered word: '46.151...'"

I also tried the following:

```
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
g1 = arcpy.FromWKT(wkt,sr)
```

But this has not led me anywhere yet... Any idea / advise welcome. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It may be worth asking your question on the [GIS.SE] Stack Exchange.

Comment: you're right! cheers

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/242313/115